# Clickhouse Dictionaries with complex MySQL queries for data source

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I want to set a lot of dictionaries in my clickhouse server and some of them aren't just plain MySQL queries to get the existing values, for a few I need to do JOINs and WHERES, and the dictionary configuration in Clickhouse only allows me to tell which MySQL table it will read the data from.
Is it possible to set a custom MySQL query for it?
Other thing that would be helpful is to use ALIASES in the attributes names.. that way I wouldn't be force to use the MySQL column name later.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use external shell script which run

```
mysql -u<user> -p<password> -h <host> -N -B -e "SELECT field AS field_alias... FROM table1 JOIN table2"
```

and try read this article
https://www.altinity.com/blog/2017/4/12/dictionaries-explained

Comment: mmm it's not the most elegant way.. but well, it can do the job until there is a better solution. Thanks.